# Fetch a field value from two associative arrays if they have one field value same

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried below jquery for fetching data from another array if they both have id common like

```
function fillVehicleDetails(vehicleDetailsArray,aggregationDriverArray, aggregationVehicleArray) {
    if (vehicleDetailsArray.length == 0){
        $("#vehicle-table").append("<tr><td>No Vehicle Added</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
    }else{
        for (var counterOfLoop in vehicleDetailsArray){                    
            noOfVehicles++;
            var SearchVehicleId = vehicleDetailsArray[counterOfLoop]["VehicleId"]['$oid'];
            var VehicleNumber =  jQuery.grep(aggregationVehicleArray, function(a){
                return a['_id']['$oid'] == SearchVehicleId}).VehicleNumber;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that aggregationVehicleArray contains data like

```
array(2)
0 => 
VehicleNumber: "JK 123"
VehicleType: "Permanent"
_id: {$oid: "5b962874d2ccda10ac003702"}

1 => 
VehicleNumber: "JK 222"
VehicleType: "Permanent"
_id: {$oid: "5b962874d2ccda10ac003686"}
```

If SearchVehicleId contains "5b962874d2ccda10ac003702" inside loop then it should fetch "JK 123" in VehicleNumber. The above code is returning "undefined"... 
Please help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning wrong value. Try this `return a['_id']['$oid'] == SearchVehicleId})[0].VehicleNumber`. As grep is storing back in array and array starts from index 0

```js
var SearchVehicleId="5b962874d2ccda10ac003702";

var aggregationVehicleArray=[
    {
     "VehicleNumber": "JK 123",
     "VehicleType": "Permanent",
     "_id": {"$oid": "5b962874d2ccda10ac003702"}
     },{
     "VehicleNumber": "JK 222",
     "VehicleType": "Permanent",
     "_id": {"$oid": "5b962874d2ccda10ac003686"}
     }
     ];
     
    var VehicleNumber =  jQuery.grep(aggregationVehicleArray, function(a){
                                           return a['_id']['$oid'] == SearchVehicleId})[0].VehicleNumber;
     
    console.log(VehicleNumber);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Lodash - Find Index](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#findIndex) is probably the right tool for solving this problem.  I recommend looking into the Lodash library in general, as it's really useful for dealing with sets and arrays in JavaScript.

`_.findIndex` solves the problem as below:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

let vehicles1 = [
    {
        VehicleNumber: "JK 123",
        VehicleType: "Permanent",
        _id: {$oid: "5b962874d2ccda10ac003702"}
    },
    {
        VehicleNumber: "JK 222",
        VehicleType: "Permanent",
        _id: {$oid: "5b962874d2ccda10ac003686"}    
    }
]

let vehicles2 = [
    {
        VehicleNumber: "JK 2-123",
        VehicleType: "Permanent",
        _id: {$oid: "5b962874d2ccda10ac001111"}
    },
    {
        VehicleNumber: "JK 2-222",
        VehicleType: "Permanent",
       _id: {$oid: "5b962874d2ccda10ac003686"}    
   }
]


for (var v in vehicles1)
{   
    let _id = vehicles1[v]._id;
    // Below is the example...
    let result = _.findIndex(vehicles2,['_id', _id]); 

    if(result > 0) {
        console.log('match: ', vehicles2[result]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to find out anything from it... please help by providing code segment